# How can I truncate these code blocks into one nested for loop?

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, if-statement

I have 4 code blocks that take values from a row and do offsets `+1, +2, +3, +4` and multiply the values under those cells (span 3 columns).

The code takes values I list in Sheet 2 and updates based off the `rIterator` variable (unique keys that show only what I need to update).

After I get the initial values in, I have to do the offset multiplication. How could I truncate this:

```
        wsA.Cells(fndRow, 3).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 2).Value
        wsA.Cells(fndRow, 4).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 3).Value
        wsA.Cells(fndRow, 5).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 4).Value

        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 1, 3).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 2).Value * 1.1
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 1, 4).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 3).Value * 1.1
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 1, 5).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 4).Value * 1.1

        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 2, 3).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 2).Value * 1.15
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 2, 4).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 3).Value * 1.15
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 2, 5).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 4).Value * 1.15

        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 3, 3).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 2).Value * 1.2
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 3, 4).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 3).Value * 1.2
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 3, 5).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 4).Value * 1.2

        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 4, 3).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 2).Value * 1.3
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 4, 4).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 3).Value * 1.3
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + 4, 5).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 4).Value * 1.3
```

into something like :

```
        For i = 0 To 4
            For j = 3 To 5
                wsA.Cells(fndRow + i, j).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value
            Next j
        Next i
```

and just implement some kind of Case statement to take care of the `1.1` `1.15` `1.2` `1.3` multipliers from the original value before the offsets?

Can provide rest of code if needed

[image: worksheet example]

EDIT: Ideally, I'd like it to look something kinda like this

```
        For i = 0 To 4
            For j = 3 To 5
            Select Case i
              Case 0
                j = 1
              Case 1
                j = 1.1
              Case 2
                j = 1.15
              Case 3
                j = 1.2
              Case 4
                j = 1.3
            End Select
            wsA.Cells(fndRow, 3 + i).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 2).Value * j
            Next j
        Next i
```

but it's not 100% there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the values in an array:

```
Dim multplr as Variant
multplr = array(1,1.1,1.15,1.2,1.3)
```

Then at the end call that based on i

```
wsA.Cells(fndRow + i, j).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value * multplr(i)
```

Comment: Nice, we came up with the same solution :D

Comment: you guys are unbelievable... is there a way I can accept both answers lol? these both work beautifully

Comment: They are both similar, choose the one you used.  The community will reward as it sees fit.  Neither of us will get our feelings hurt if you choose the other. @nicklanta

Comment: thank you both so much, again, really appreciate it!

Comment: I have one related question that fits within that nest for loop. If I inserted columns into Sheet1, and the values being updated are now in columns R-T instead of C-E, how would I adjust that accordingly? 

I tried changing `for j = 3 to 5`, but that is now screwing up the output

Answer (score 2):

I think this code should do the trick:

```
Dim multiplier(0 To 4) As Double
multiplier(0) = 1
multiplier(1) = 1.1
multiplier(2) = 1.15
multiplier(3) = 1.2
multiplier(4) = 1.3

For i = 0 To 4
    For j = 3 To 5
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + i, j).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value * multiplier(i)
    Next j
Next i
```